# Having issues resolving compiler error C2678

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, c++17, operator-keyword

Here is my code:

**Register.h**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>

namespace vpc {

    using u8  = std::uint8_t;
    using u16 = std::uint16_t;
    using u32 = std::uint32_t;
    using u64 = std::uint64_t;

    template<typename T>
    struct Register {
        T data;
        T value;
        std::bitset<sizeof(T)* CHAR_BIT> bits;

        Register() = default;

        template<typename P>
        explicit Register(const P val) :
            data{ static_cast<T>(val) },
            value{ data },
            bits{ data }
        {}

        template<typename P>
        Register(const P val, const u8 idx) :
            data{ static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned<T>>::max()) },
            value{ data },
            bits{ data }
        {
            assert(idx >= '\0' && idx < sizeof(T));
        }

        template<typename P>
        Register(const Register<P>& reg) :
            data{ static_cast<T>(reg.data) },
            value{ data },
            bits{ data }
        {}

        template<typename P>
        Register(const Register<P>& reg, const u8 idx) :
            data{ static_cast<T>((reg.data >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
                  std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned<T>>::max()) },
            value{ data },
            bits{ data }
        {
            assert(idx >= 0 && idx < sizeof(T));
        }

    };

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Register<T>& r) {
        return os << "Reg" << std::size(r.bits) << '(' << +r.data << ")\nhex: 0x"
            << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T) * 2) << std::hex
            << +r.data << std::dec << "\nbin: "
            << r.bits << "\n\n";
    }

    using Reg8 =  Register<u8>;
    using Reg16 = Register<u16>;
    using Reg32 = Register<u32>;
    using Reg64 = Register<u64>;

} // namespace vpc
```

In my main function where I'm using this class, the default constructor works, the second constructor works
by passing in both values and variables. The third constructor is giving me a compiler error.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Register.h"

int main() {
    using namespace vpc;

    u16 val = 0xC97B;

    Reg8 r8low( val, 0 );  // should be 7B
    Reg8 r8high( val, 1 ); // should be C9

    std::cout << r8low << r8high;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the compiler error I'm getting from Visual Studio 2017:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestRegister, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\***\register.h(38): error C2678: binary '&': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cstddef(45): note: could be 'std::byte std::operator &(const std::byte,const std::byte) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>c:\***\register.h(39): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int, _Ty)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::make_unsigned<vpc::u8>
1>        ]
1>c:\***\main.cpp(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::Register<vpc::u16>(const P,const vpc::u8)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            P=vpc::u16
1>        ]
1>c:\***\main.cpp(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'vpc::Register<vpc::u8>::Register<vpc::u16>(const P,const vpc::u8)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            P=vpc::u16
1>        ]
1>Done building project "TestRegister.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I understand what the compiler error is; but I don't know what exact is causing it. Is it coming from `std::size` or `std::numeric_limits<...>()` ? It does say left hand side so I'm assuming `std::size()`...

I don't know how to resolve this. What can I do in order to be able to compile this? I'm almost certain if this constructor is causing this error, then my last constructor would probably cause the same or similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `std::make_unsigned<T>` to `std::make_unsigned_t<T>` (or `typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type` before C++14); You want the corresponding unsigned type, not [`std::make_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned) itself. i.e.

```
template<typename P>
Register(const P val, const u8 idx) :
    data{ static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) &
          std::numeric_limits<std::make_unsigned_t<T>>::max()) },
//                                              ^^
    value{ data },
    bits{ data }
{
    assert(idx >= '\0' && idx < sizeof(T));
}
```

Comment: It's always good to have a second set or pair of eyes! Any eyes will work too they even could be variant for that matter.

Comment: I kind of have another question regarding the same code above, however I do not feel like writing a full new question and I don't want to add to this one above because it is a completely different and irrelevant issue. I can try to describe my intentions in the comments here although it does pertain to the same constructor... it has to do with the calculations for my `assert(...)`

Comment: My `Reg8`, `Reg16`, `Reg32` & `Reg64` contain 1,2,4 & 8 bytes and 8, 16, 32 & 64 bits in the `bitset`. It pertains to when I'm creating a smaller size register from either a larger size value or larger size register with an index value. If I'm constructing a `Reg8` from a `u16` or `Reg16` the index range is  `[0,1]`, `Reg8` from `u32` or `Reg32` range is `[0,3]`, `Reg8` from `u64` or `Reg64` range is `[0,7]`, `Reg16` from `u32` or `Reg32` range is `[0,1]`, `Reg16` from `u64` or `Reg64` range is `[0,4]` and `Reg32` from `u64` or `Reg64` range is `[0,1]`. Is my calculation correct?

Comment: Okay no problem thought I might ask though... I can do a rigorous unit testing to see if my asserts work or fail... and to see where they fail at in each case.

Comment: I think I figured it out, The lower bound is always `0` simple enough. The upper bound depends on both `sizeof(T)` the type it is and `sizeof(P)` the type being constructed from. So the equation for the upper bound appears to be `(sizeof(P) / sizeof(T)) - 1;`